# onSizeChanged/Custom View Classes In Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I need to have a class which extends view that overrides the onSizeChanged method in order to keep track of the size of one of my view elements.  I have another class which manages this view and I'd like to have that class accept my view as a View, not as a Sized view.  Essentially, I'd like to make the fact that I'm override the onSizeChanged method transparent to the user of the class (of the managing class).

When my management class accepts the view, I need to cast the View to my custom view class.  Unfortunately when I do this I get a classcastexception.

This is the function where I am failing.  Also, this.root is of type SizeView

```
public void setContentView(View view) {
    this.root = (SizeView) view;
    this.window.setContentView(view);
}
```

Is it possible to do this?  Or alternatively, what is the best way to monitor the onSizeChanged method of one of my view variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the variable `view` that you pass in was initialized as a `SizeView`. A bit more information on casting [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/why-down-casting-throws-classcastexception/125).

You should also check whether `view` is actually of type `SizeView` before casting it. So use `view instanceof SizeView` and then if it is true do your cast.

Comment: So if view is already a SizeView it effectively removes that transparency that I mentioned.  Is there anyway to do this without requiring the users of my class to init view as a SizeView?